# Green Android camera notification

Tags: security, camera, notification-icons

Since this morning, the green camera icon on the top right of the status bar appears. When I open this notification, it says "In use by Google". The problem is that I don't have any app opened.

Why would Google need to open my camera in the background?
Anyone got into this situation?

Comment: Have you enabled facial recognition? The camera is in use for this then.

Comment: @wbogacz, That's the first thing I thought about but no it is not enabled. Thanks. That's why I was a bit worried. I reboot the phone and since, no camera icon anymore. It is pretty weird that it was on. Just wanted to know if someone esle met the same situation.